# Magento 2 : How to change print and PDF logo?

Tags: magento2, frontend, logo

I want to set print logo different as per website logo.

> Is it possible to set different logo for print and PDF in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes and it's pretty simple. Stores > Sales > Sales (not PDF Print-outs as you might expect). Half way down there's a section for Invoice and Packing Slip Design.

[image]

Comment: I have uploaded logo image having dimensions as 200X50. However the image on pdf is blurred and takes size about 308X79. Any idea why is it taking these dimensions?

Comment: 400x100px image will look better,  but it looks big. I tried with the ratio: 900x100. OK better